# How to Register a New Layer on a Neural Network in OpenCV DNN on Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, javacpp

I am developing an OpenCV based edge detection package in Android using Kotlin.
I have imported the [OpenCV Java CPP Presets Package](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv). I am using the DNN Module.

I have to register a new layer to complete my model like https://github.com/legolas123/cv-tricks.com/blob/master/OpenCV/Edge_detection/edge.py Line 42.

The [package](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/dnn/Layer.html) mentions the following line

> Also before using the new layer into networks you must register your layer by using one of REF: dnnLayerFactory "LayerFactory" macros.

Please, can someone explain how to do this in Kotlin?

In CPP, the following MACROS can be used https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d8c/layer_8details_8hpp.html#a7e8d9c0c5849b6a081ba2a84845f3dac

Comment: This needs to be done in C++, potentially as another library that depends on OpenCV: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Create-New-Presets

Comment: @SamuelAudet But the library already exposes the Layer Factory: https://javadoc.io/static/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/3.4.0-1.4/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_dnn.LayerFactory.html Isn't there any way to just use this simply?
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like it. As far as I understand, it expects the user to create new C++ classes, although I may be mistaken...